# Get update for light/dark mode theme change

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI app, in which I have a SpriteKit scene. However, when changing between light and dark mode, **the scene background does not change colour until the app is reopened**.

This is not ideal, so I want to register when the light/dark mode appearance is changed. The colour in my assets has an "any" and a "dark" appearance.

> Code inside `updateUIView()` within a `UIViewRepresentable` struct, which sets up the scene when it is linked with SwiftUI:

```
scene.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "Color.Scene")!
uiView.presentScene(scene)
```

How do I achieve this? I am using iOS 13's system wide dark mode, so I do not want a solution of Notification Center because all I am looking to do is update the background according to the system settings.

Comment: Can you use `@Environment (\.colorScheme) var colorScheme: ColorScheme` in your view and `if self.colorScheme == .light { ... } else { ... }` in the body like this? The view will update when it changes.

Comment: So if the colour scheme changes, how do I get the `if` to run?

Comment: It does it automatically since it is treated like a `@State`. If you edit the question and provide more sample code, I'll try to give you an example

Comment: @krjw Thanks for the help! The environment variable fixed it. I placed that in the SwiftUI View holding my `UIViewRepresentable`. Then, in the constructor, I set the colour of the scene like I showed in my question, as the theme is set automatically.

Comment: no problem, shall I answer the question then?

Comment: @krjw I also didn't need to use the `colorScheme` variable, but without this, it wouldn't work.

Comment: @MattisSchulte I was already using a Color Set. The problem was that SwiftUI cannot update a UIColor. Anyway, someone has provided the solution :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `@Environment (\.colorScheme) var colorScheme: ColorScheme` in your view and make the views `body` react to it:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment (\.colorScheme) var colorScheme: ColorScheme

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            if self.colorScheme == .light { 
                // draw for light mode
            } else { 
                // draw for dark mode
            }
        }
    }
}
```